# replace value and rebuild the json data python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I have a scenario where I have below json data

```
 data = {
      "app": [
        {
          "ida": 10,
          "configur": {
            "config": [
              {
                "active": "true",
                "tol": "id"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "ida": 11,
          "configur": {
            "config": [
              {
                "active": "true",
                "tol": "id"
              }
            ]
          }
        },    {
          "ida": 11,
          "configur": {
            "config": [
              {
                "active": "true",
                "tol": "id"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here I want to replace the `tol` value with the `ida` in each element

Here is my code :

```
  data3 = []
  for cmpkey2 in data['app']:
        spcmpg = cmpkey2['configur']['config']
        tempev = cmpkey2['ida']
        for key34 in spcmpg:
            key34['tol'] = tempev
        data3.append({ "ida": tempev, "config": spcmpg})
```

Here the new dict `data3` is not replacing the `tol` value with `ida` value , Where am I doing wrong here ?
any help would be great !!

Answer (score 0):

In case of a dictionary you cant change name of a key, you can either delete that key or create a new key

and i found a solution for your problem,

```
data = {
      "app": [
        {
          "ida": 10,
          "configur": {
            "config": [
              {
                "active": "true",
                "tol": "id"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "ida": 11,
          "configur": {
            "config": [
              {
                "active": "true",
                "tol": "id"
              }
            ]
          }
        },    {
          "ida": 11,
          "configur": {
            "config": [
              {
                "active": "true",
                "tol": "id"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }

val=''
data3 = []
for cmpkey2 in data['app']:
    spcmpg = cmpkey2['configur']['config']

    tempev = cmpkey2['ida']
    for key34 in spcmpg:

        val=cmpkey2['ida']
        key34['tol']=val


    data3.append({ "ida": tempev, "config": spcmpg})
print(data3)
```

In this code it creates a new key and assigns value of `tol` to that key and then delete the `tol` key

output:

```
[{'ida': 10, 'config': [{'active': 'true', 'tol': 10}]}, {'ida': 11, 'config': [{'active': 'true', 'tol': 11}]}, {'ida': 11, 'config': [{'active': 'true', 'tol': 11}]}]
```

Comment: I am seeking to replace the value of `tol` thats `id` so `id` value should be replaced by `ida`

Comment: I have edited my answer , have a look at it and let me know if something is wrong

Comment: Doesn't works only takes the last value of id `11` and appends to all other `tol` values so the output I get is 
`[{'ida': 10, 'config': [{'active': 'true', 'tol': 11}]}, {'ida': 11, 'config': [{'active': 'true', 'tol': 11}]}, {'ida': 11, 'config': [{'active': 'true', 'tol': 11}]}]`

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below code and see if this is how u expect your output to be

```
data3 = []

for item in data['app']:
    new_dict = {}
    config_list = []
    ida_value = item['ida']
    config_list = item['configur']['config']
    config_list[0]['tol'] = ida_value
    new_dict['ida'] = ida_value
    new_dict['config'] = config_list
    data3.append(new_dict)
print(data3)
```

Output

```
[
   {
      "ida":10,
      "config":[
         {
            "active":"true",
            "tol":10
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "ida":11,
      "config":[
         {
            "active":"true",
            "tol":11
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "ida":11,
      "config":[
         {
            "active":"true",
            "tol":11
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: I am not sure why this is ahppening but still I get this output
`[{'ida': 10, 'config': [{'active': 'true', 'tol': 11}]}, {'ida': 11, 'config': [{'active': 'true', 'tol': 11}]}, {'ida': 11, 'config': [{'active': 'true', 'tol': 11}]}]`
the last element is appended in all the `tol` values

Comment: Is this a loop problem as I see only the last element value is getting saved

Comment: did u use the code i gave ? and still got 11 everywhere?

Comment: @John According to the code i wrote above I had got the provided output and that is what u r expecting right. Not quite sure using the same code i wrote how u r getting a different response.